# Сохранение значений переменных,и их последующая инициализация

Tags: python, python-2.x

Ранее задавал вопрос: [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528788/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0/528789?noredirect=1#comment658193_528789).

На него мне ответили. Но у меня вопрос, как всё это реализовать. Буду благодарен за пример кода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, используя модуль [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

```
import json

config = dict()
config['x'] = 1
config['y'] = 1
config['window'] = {
    'title': 'Simple'
}

print config

# Сохранение в файл
json.dump(config, open('config', mode='w'), indent=' ' * 4)

# Чтение из файла
config2 = json.load(open('config'))
print config2
```

Файл `config`:

```
{
    "y": 1,
    "window": {
        "title": "Simple"
    },
    "x": 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Самый банальный пример с [ini-файлом](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html).